# Cannot create line break with Enter key in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, ide

Since last update (V1.77.0) the Enter key doesn't work to create a line break in VS Code editor.

Anybody else experience the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also check this github issue: [Enter key is not working](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178782).  (And https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178788)

The [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=diegolincoln.vscode-styled-components) extension has been identified by a few people as the problem.

---

From the issue:

> This problem indeed is caused by the
> diegolincoln.vscode-styled-components extension because of the new VS
> Code when-clause parser.
>
> I tried sending a PR to this extension fixing the syntax error it has
> (which was just ignored by the previous parser), but it seems the
> extension (at least its repository) is archived. It seems like there's
> a new vscode-styled-components extension that's very popular -
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components
>
> Workarounds   Option 1 (recommended)
>
> This particular extension seems unmaintained. I strongly suggest
> switching to using this extension if it fits your needs -
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components
>
> Option 2
>
> Remove that keybinding: invoke "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts"
> from the Command Palette, search "enter", and right-click on the
> command contributed by vscode-styled-components (see right-most column
> for the source of the keybinding)

[image: change old keybinding]

> I will close this issue because this extension is unmaintained. I
> recommend switching to
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components,
> which seems to be very active and fixes this keybinding in several
> ways (both the syntax error and integration with auto-completion)

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled the styled components vs code extension and solved the root issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution.

In the keyboard shortcuts JSON (keybindings.json file) I added this:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "type",
  "args": {
  "text": "\n"
},
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
},
```

Now the Enter key works as expected in the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just  Disable this extension and it will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would reply to this with my experience in case it helps anyone.  For me, what worked was to hit the Migrate button on the vscode-styled-components extension.

[image: Not this extension, but an example of the Migrate button I'm talking about]